# React и событие onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть простейший компонент - форма. В нём инпут и кнопка. Подскажите, почему, если на кнопку, повесить событие onClick и записать так: `onClick = {() => console.log(value)}`, то код работает (для меня) ожидаемо, т.е. я что-то вписываю в инпут, жму на кнопку и вижу в консоли, содержимое инпута.
Но, если, записать вот так: `onClick = {console.log(value)}`, то данные выводятся в консоль, сразу же, после изменений в инпуте, не дожидаясь клика по кнопке.
Другими словами, в чем разница, между записями `onClick = {() => console.log(value)}` и `onClick = {console.log(value)}`, на примере моего компонента?

```js
import { Component } from "react";

export default class ItemAdder extends Component {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });
  };
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    let {value} = this.state;
    return (
      <form className="formAdd" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.value}
          placeholder="Add ToDo item here"
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
        />

        <button className="add"
         onClick = {console.log(value)}>+</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При вот такой записи

```js
onClick = {() => console.log(value)}
```

вы инициализируете функцию (callback), которая будет исполняться только при наступлении события `event`'a. Ничего такого в этом нет и будет работать, как и должно, но есть одно НО: *при каждом рендере будет создаваться новая функция*. Это надо учитывать и вот такой вид не то, чтобы правильней, но позволяет избегать некоторых ошибок

```js
clickMe = () =>{
  console.log(this.state);
}
....
  render() {
...
    <button className="add"
         onClick = {this.clickMe}>+</button>
...
}
```

или

```
clickMe(){
  console.log(this.state);
}
....
  render() {
...
    <button className="add"
         onClick = {() = > this.clickMe()}>+</button>
...
}
```

В противном случае запись

```js
onClick = {console.log(value)}
```

вы буквально говорите -> "При рендере в слушатель onClick передать это - вывести в консоль value". А должно быть -> "При рендере определить/передать функцию (callback) которая исполняется при наступлении события"

**UPD** здесь наверное необходимо погружение в то, что называется `callback`. [Здесь можно почитать](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Callback_function). А вот насколько глубоко вы собрались погружаться, я не знаю. Весь код открыт, можете проследить как определен `onClick`.
Пример:
Определение `button`

```js
button: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>;
```

Какие пропсы

```js
type DetailedHTMLProps<E extends HTMLAttributes<T>, T> = ClassAttributes<T> & E;
```

Смотрим от что наследуем `HTMLAttributes`

```js
interface DOMAttributes<T> {
        children?: ReactNode | undefined;
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML?: {
            __html: string;
        } | undefined;
......
        // MouseEvents
        onAuxClick?: MouseEventHandler<T> | undefined;
        onAuxClickCapture?: MouseEventHandler<T> | undefined;
        onClick?: MouseEventHandler<T> | undefined;
```

и так далее

Comment: Ок, спасибо, как фиксить - разобрался. Но до меня, увы, всё никак не доходит, почему срабатывает событие, хотя по сути, я его не генерил. Я ведь не жал на кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

`() => console.log(value)` - это функция. Если ее передать в `onClick`, то она будет вызвана, когда произойдет событие `click`.

`console.log(value)` - это вызов функции, который возвращает `undefined`. Если его передать в `onClick`, то это все равно что передать `onClick={undefined}` - то есть на событие ничего вызываться не будет. А вывод в консоль происходит при вызове `render()`, который происходит каждый раз при изменении инпута (= изменение стейта).

Comment: Не могли бы уточнить, почему "console.log(value) - это вызов функции, который возвращает undefined"? Вроде бы в коде, который в примере, value у нас всегда имеет какое-то значение

Comment: `console.log` - это функция, `console.log()` - вызов этой функции. Если сделать `let x = console.log(value)`, то в консоль выведется значение `value`, но значение `x` будет `undefined`